# Silverlight GetElementById IE6

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, silverlight, internet-explorer-6

I have an odd error that you guys will hopefully be able to help me out with.

I have this code in my silverlight app:

```
private void MainGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
double actualHeight = this.MainGrid.ActualHeight;
HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("silverlightControlHost").SetStyleAttribute("height", string.Format("{0}px", actualHeight));
}
```

This basically resizes my container div so that it fits in the browser. This is working fine in IE7+, Firefox and Chrome. The problem is that in IE6 this is not working. And im not sure why.

Page markup:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #silverlightControlHost
        {
            height: 10px; //This gets resized in Chrome/IE7+/Firefox
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Silverlight.js"></script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
            width="100%" height="100%">
            <param name="enablehtmlaccess" value="true"/>
            <param name="source" value="../ClientBin/myAppXap.xap" />
            <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
            <param name="background" value="white" />
            <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40624.0" />
            <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
            <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40624.0" style="text-decoration: none">
                <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                    style="border-style: none" />
            </a>
        </object>
        <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;
            border: 0px"></iframe>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Does anyone have any ideas how i can get this working as desired?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: In IE6, the DiV "silverlightControlHost" will remain at 10px. In all other browsers this is resizing as desired to the size of the silverlight content so that it fits correctly into the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to resize your object tag as well, i just had the same problem, i had signed the onsizechanged event and changed the height and width of the container div, however in IE6 that didn't worked, so a co-worker told me that in IE6 you need to resize the object as well, so place an ID on your  tag and use it on this

```
HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("objectID").SetStyleAttribute("height", string.Format("{0}px", actualHeight));
```